# How to check duplicate values in multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have an associative multidimensional array with multiple state ids:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "url" => "http://www.kerluke.net/qui-sint-debitis-quo-et-suscipit-dolores-dolor-quae"
    "us_states_ids" => array:2 [
      0 => "15"
      1 => "16"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "url" => "http://www.migato.net/qui-sint-debitis-quo-et-suscipit-dolores-dolor-quae"
    "us_states_ids" => array:3 [
      0 => "15"
      1 => "24"
      2 => "28"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Now I want to find duplicate ids for us_states_ids as you can see index 1 has id of 15 same as index 2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looping the array and play around with array_intersect on current "us_state_ids" with the previous one if it is not the first iteration.

```
$duplicates = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $prevStateIds = $arr[$i - 1]["us_states_ids"];
    $stateIds = $arr[$i]["us_states_ids"];
    $duplicates = array_merge($dupicates, array_intersect($prevStateIds, $stateIds));
  }
}
```

then `$duplicates` will have the duplicates. The above code is untested, it's just for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect()` to get duplicates:

```
$duplicates = [];
foreach($arr as $a) {
    foreach($arr as $b) {
        if ($a !== $b) {
            $duplicates = [ ...$duplicates, ...array_intersect($a["us_states_ids"], $b["us_states_ids"]) ];
        }
    }
}
$duplicates = array_unique($duplicates);
```

Comment: You're welcome. The two solutions are more or less the same. Use which one you like better :)